# How to inject a generic interface into MVC controller using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have the following situation:

- an interface:

  ```
  public interface ITest<T> where T:class
   {
      void Delete(T item);
   }
  ```
- the abstract implementation:

  ```
   public abstract class Test<T>:ITest<T> where T:class 
      {
          private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

          protected Test(ApplicationDbContext context){
          _context=context;
          }
          public void Delete(T item) { }
      }
  ```
- final class:

  ```
  public class RepoTest:Test<FirstEntity>
  {
     public void DoSomething() { }
  }
  ```

I have a MVC Controller, which looks like this:

```
 public abstract class MyController<T>:Controller where T:class 
    {
        private readonly ITest<T> _test;
        protected MyController(ITest<T> test)
        {
            _test = test;
        }
    }
```

For each entity, I create a controller, inherited from MyController, and base on Entity I want ninject to inject the specific class.

For this I try to use this bindings:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(ITest<>)).To(typeof(Test<>)).InRequestScope();

           kernel.Bind(x=>x.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(Test<>))
           .SelectAllClasses()
           .InheritedFrom(typeof(Test<>))
           .BindToSelf());
```

Unfortunatly I alwasys got this kind of errors:

> Error activating ITest{Tool}
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>    2) Injection of dependency ITest{Tool} into parameter test of constructor of type ToolsController
>    1) Request for ToolsController
>
> Suggestions:  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for
>   ITest{Tool}.  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that
>   the module has been loaded into the kernel.  3) Ensure you have not
>   accidentally created more than one kernel.  4) If you are using
>   constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the
>   constructors parameter name.  5) If you are using automatic module
>   loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

**How can I tell to Ninject, to inject the class base on the Entity type?**

Comment: The exception text references class `ToolsController` which is not present in the listing. can you show it please?

Comment: Also, please show the constructor for `Test<T>`

Comment: I edited my post and now is visible the constructor. I am looking for a way to have a bacth binding method, because I have more then 50 entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as it is written currently won't work.

You have two options:

1. Use generic:

Because your controller is expecting `ITest<T>` which is bound to an `abstract` class `Test<T>` which can't be instantiated.

You have to make a concrete but Generic class `Test<T>` and add a binding for `ApplicationDbContext` which will automatically work.

2. Use Reflection to find the right type at binding, e.g.:

Important!!! remove both of your `kernel.Bind()` calls.

```
 // this will find classes which, like RepoTest, are derived from Test<>
var allDerivedTypes = typeof(Test<>).Assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType.IsGenericType && x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Test<>)).ToList();

// ideally, you'd find some way to constrain all your models.
// what you need for this foreach is all of the entities that can be present in things like RepoTest
foreach(var t in typeof(Tool).Assembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    // For each entity, get a runtime representation of Test<Entity>
    var targetType = typeof(Test<>).MakeGenericType(t);

    // Check if there is a class derived from Test<Entity>
    var potentiallyPresentImplementation = allDerivedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => targetType == x.BaseType); // here you might want to decide how to handle multiple instances of the same generic base

    // Found one, so bind it
    if(potentiallyPresentImplementation != null)
    {
        kernel.Bind(targetType ).To(potentiallyPresentImplementation ).InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

Note: method 2 is currently assuming that all models and `Test<>` derivatives are in one assmebly, respecitvely. You'd need to add a little more reflection magic to inspect all referenced assemblies if this is not the case.

After this, the controller will get `RepoTest` injected. Although to be honest with you, approach 1. is better :)